# How do I use an npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

So I really love the concept of npm and nodejs, but I am having a hard time grasping css most less JavaScript and I'm aware that's a huge part of the problem. But I guess what I'm asked is when I npm install a package, how do I

1. List ALL of the possible commands and/or scripts for the package?
2. Use said package as a standalone by itself?

For example Tinycme WYSIWYG package I installed globally and can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: Every package is different. You have to use the package's documentation to figure out what it does. npm is a package manager. If you type npm without arguments it will show you all available commands.

Comment: ^ Those would be the built-in commands for `npm` itself though.

Comment: You will need to know basic javascript to use nodejs. Do yourself a favor and expect to spend a couple of months in basic javascript/html/css tutorials before trying to learn node

Comment: @FelixKling: correct. That's why I said that each package is documented by its authors separately

Comment: @DovRine I understand, I just wanted to make sure that that part of the comment is not misunderstood as an answer to (1).

Comment: @FelixKling: In re-reading my original answer, I can see how my intention could be misread. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score -2):

Using npm packages in your projects: https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm-packages-in-your-projects

Once you have [installed](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-locally) a package in node_modules, you can use it in your code.

**Node.js module**

If you are creating a Node.js module, you can use a package in your module by passing it as an argument to the require function.

```
var lodash = require('lodash');
var output = lodash.without([1, 2, 3], 1);
console.log(output);
```

**package.json file**

In package.json, list the package under dependencies. You can optionally include a semantic version.

```
{
   "dependencies": {
      "@package_name": "^1.0.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Plagiarized from the link at the top.